# How to merge downloaded video in youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

Some streaming websites split the video into multiple parts and youtube-dl downloads all files to its directory. Is it possible to issue youtube-dl to merge the files together (into MKV)?

[`--merge-output-format mkv`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#video-format-options) has no impact in this scenario.

FFmpeg is installed.

Comment: I have serious doubts that what you want is possible. The videos are always merged I think. Youtube seems to offer both streams separately so even when youtube-dl offers presets like "best quality", they are muxed.

Answer (score 2):

The flag you specified only combines audio and video tracks from the same video into one, not what you are looking for. If you want to merge multiple videos together, you can use FFmpeg. This StackOverflow answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/1709894

Comment: youtube-dl -f 248+251 video-url will do the trick, no need for ffmpeg.

Comment: @sinekonata Thank you it works well. The only things that needs to be taken care of is that both the audio and video should be of the same format to be merged.